# Not able to append to an existing file in java

Tags: java

I am new to programming. I am working on a scenario where I am getting values from datatable (cucumber) multiple times and converting it into string each time and need to save all these strings to a single file.

**Cucumber File Steps:**

```
And I have added goods details for "Chocolates"
|Product.Name| Daily Milk|
|Product.Weight| 40g|
|Product.MRP | 20.00|
And I have added goods details for "Biscuits"
|Product.Name| Monaco|
|Product.Weight| 20g|
|Product.MRP | 5.00|
```

**Step Def:**

```
@And("I have added goods details for {string}")

public void iHaveAddedGoodsDetails(String goodsName, DataTable dtable) {
    HashMap<String, DataTable> details = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    details.put(goodsName, dTable);
    String body = "{\n" +
              "\"Product\": {\n" + 
              "\"Name\" : \"" + details.get(goodsName).row(0).get(1) + "\",\n" +
              "\"Weight\" : \"" + details.get(goodsName).row(1).get(1) + "\",\n" +
              "\"Price\" : \"" + details.get(goodsName).row(2).get(1) + "\",\n" +
              "}\n" +
              "}";
    FileWriter fout = new FileWriter("path", true);
    fout.writeToFile(body);
}
```

**writeToFile method is in separate class which is as follows:**

```
public void writeToFile(String str) {
    try(OutputStreamwriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(path + ".json"),
            StandardCharsets.UTF-8)) {
        writer.write(str);
        writer.flush();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Actual Output:

```
    {
    "Product": {
    "Name": "Monaco",
    "Weight": "20g",
    "MRP": "5.00"
    }
   }
```

Expected Output:

```
{
"Product": {
"Name": "Dairy Milk",
"Weight": "40g",
"MRP": "20.00"
}
}
{
"Product": {
"Name": "Monaco",
"Weight": "20g",
"MRP": "5.00"
}
}
```

I am not sure where I am doing wrong.. any help will be appreciated!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your code doesn't make a lot of sense.

```
FileWriter fout = new FileWriter("path", true);
fout.writeToFile(body);
```

The standard `java.io.FileWriter` class does not have a `writeToFile` method.  So you must have (unwisely, IMO) created your own `FileWriter` with the same name as the standard one but in a different package.

But then your `writeToFile` method is

```
public void writeToFile(String str) {
    try (OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(path + ".json"),
            StandardCharsets.UTF-8)) {
        writer.write(str);
        writer.flush();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you look carefully, it is ignoring `this`, and creating another `Writer` to write the `str` to.  And it is opening the file like this:

```
new FileOutputStream(path + ".json"),
```

Notice, it did NOT open it in append mode.

It will clobber the previous content of the file rather than appending to it.

---

The direct solution is to change

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(path + ".json"),
            StandardCharsets.UTF-8)
```

to

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path + ".json", StandardCharsets.UTF-8, true)
```

But to make this work, you will **also** need to get rid of your custom `FileWriter` class, and make the `writeToFile` a method of some other class.

Basically, you need to rethink how you have structured the code.

Finally, avoid borrowing the names of existing Java SE classes for your own classes.  It leads to confusion and problems.  Use a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html)

Solution: 
Use this [FileWriter(String fileName, Charset charset, boolean append)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.nio.charset.Charset,boolean))

Replace:

```java
OutputStreamwriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(path + ".json"),
            StandardCharsets.UTF-8)`
```

With:

```java
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path + ".json", StandardCharsets.UTF-8, true)
```